# Как создать ограниченный радиус движения для объекта в игре на Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

```
public void Update () {
          Vector3 diffarance = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
             float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(diffarance.y, diffarance.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);
     }
```

С помощью вышеуказанного кода я могу создать для "пушки" в игре вращение на 360 градусов. Как можно узнать из этого кода, "пушка" следует за движением указателя мыши и при этом условии вращается на 360 градусов. Вопрос в том, как я могу создать ограниченный радиус движения "пушки" между значениями X и Y ?? Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь использовать `Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)`. Он возвращает значение `value`, установленное между "граничными" значениями `min` и `max`
(справка: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html).

Перед присваиванием `transform.rotation =` ты можешь "заклампить" полученные значения, тем самым ограничив до определённых границ получаемое вращение.